# How to create a multi track player (like a dj mixer) for iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, html, actionscript-3, tablet

I would like to create a multi track player (like a dj mixer) for a website.

I've tried to create it with html 5 but it doesn't work on safari iOS (iPad, iPhone) because it's not possible to play several sounds at the same time with <audio>

```
<audio src='audio/son-AMBIANCE.mp3' id="yourAudio" preload='auto' autoplay loop></audio>
<audio src='audio/son-MUSIQUE.mp3' id="yourAudio" preload='auto' autoplay loop></audio>
<audio src='audio/son-VOIX.mp3' id="yourAudio" preload='auto' autoplay loop></audio>
```

On iOS, only the first mp3 is played.

I think about this solution : create an app.

Do you think it's possible to create a dj mixer in objective C ? Or even better for me, create a dj mixer with flash and export it for Android and iOS (better for me because i know actionScript 3).

Do you think it is a good idea and it is technically feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an AIR application with the latest [Gaming SDK](http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/gamingsdk/) from Adobe which will work well on Android and IOS. It will give you everything you need to create a smooth DJ mixer sort of application and run multiple sound files at once.  However if you have any very large lists, some users might complain about the sluggishness of the large list (over 30 items)

You can also create the application in IOS and provided you use the correct file formats, you can play multiple layers of Audio.

I recommend using AIR if the application is visually simple with only a few objects in a list being displayed at a time, and Objective C for IOS or Java for Andorid if you have very heavy animations or extremely large lists of songs.

Comment: The link in your comment is really interesting. I'm actually reading it. About the mixer specifications, i have only 4 tracks played at the same time but the users could drag and drop new songs from a list of 100 tracks. Do you know if the songs in the application can be loaded from the internet or if they have to be embedded in the app ? As i say, i know as3 but i've never done app for iOS and Android with flash.

Comment: You can load in the music files from the internet.
If you have over 100 tracks, I suggest using a paging or filter system to only display a few at a time.

Comment: I've enrolled to Apple Developer program. I've created an app "dj mixer" with flash and install it on my iPad. It seems to work. I have a lot of work of course in order to finish it but you help me to start. Thanks.